# How to create a Template function that creates an instance of the class specified as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to enumerate my I2C bus. I have a data structure that contains the I2C address range, the device name and a pointer to the function that needs to be called to "Create" that device.
The Create Device functions are all very similar and I was wondering if I can create a template function, instead of creating n functions that only differ in the name of the device that they are creating
A typical create function looks like this (the name AMS3935Creator is stashed in the data structure above and when that device is encountered, this function is called).

```
I2cDeviceBase * AMS3935Creator ( I2cInterfaceBase & i2cBus, uint8_t i2cAddress, DeviceFactory * dfObject )
{
  return new AMS3935 ( i2cBus, i2cAddress ) ;
}
```

I tried to work this out like this, but the template function does not compile (See error comment below), is there a way to accomplish this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class BaseClass {
  protected:
    BaseClass () {} ;
    BaseClass ( int param1, int param2 ) { printf ( "in BaseClass Constructor\n" ) ; } ;

} ;

class ClassA : public BaseClass {
  public: 
   // ClassA () {} ;
    ClassA ( int param1, int param2 ) { printf ( "in ClassA Constructor\n" ) ; } ;
  } ;

class ClassB : public BaseClass {
  public: 
    ClassB () {} ;
    ClassB ( int param1, int param2 ) { printf ( "in ClassB Constructor\n" ) ; } ;
} ;

template <typename ClassName> 
  BaseClass * TemplateTest( int param1, int param2, ClassName className ) {
    BaseClass * bcPointer = new className ( param1, param2 ) ; // error: expected type-specifier before ‘className’
    return bcPointer ;
}
```

Comment: As for your immediate error, your "new" is followed by "className" but the type argument is "ClassName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your title question

```
template<typename T> 
T create(){  return T{}; }
```

As to you actual question. It is most of the time very tricky, sometimes bordering on impossible to make templates and inheritance play nice with each other.  Also `ClassName className` in the argument list makes `className` a value.  You cant do

```
new value; // needs to be a type.
```

If this was intended to be `ClassName`, see my first suggestion.

My suggestion is: Scrap this design and redo it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, any advice for the "proper" way to do this enumeration. I want to be able to create devices based on the i2c addresses detected and generate an instance of the class that handler for that type of device. The code I have works, but results in a lot of repetition of very similar code, differing only by the handler that is created.

Comment: @JoeSimon No need to start complex. Add abstractions when it simplifies things.  If you run into trouble you might have luck at the code-review site.